# Is there any raw TCP library in C or C++?

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, network-programming, kernel

I going to create kernel mode driver level app that establish a TCP connection, here is my requirement:

1. I don’t want pass data to user-mode
2. I don’t want use winsocket and OS socket library
3. I need to just pass tcp packet to a library and
   the library create simple TCP-client or TCP-Server connection for me. It should perform all TCP connection requirements such as tcp handshake, generate packet, calculate checksum, set TCP flags and acknowledgment then give the new packet to me so I can send the packet to my network adapter.

Do you know exiting TCP implementation that it does not use OS socket library?

Comment: Reinventing winsock?  Really?

Comment: An OS tag (Window, linux...) would be more useful than a programming language tag (C++).

Comment: Can you show us what you've found out so far?

Answer (score 3):

I think the proper way to ask this question is this:

> What is the proper way to do TCP sockets within kernel code?

And I'm not sure you want to do TCP just at the packet level, because you'll also likely want to handle TCP segmentation, IP fragmentaion, sending only when the remote window size permits it, and ACK generation.  In other words, if you're doing a TCP server within kernel mode, you want the whole kernel TCP stack.

In any case, Bing or Google around for "kernel sockets" or "ksocket".

For Linux: http://ksocket.sourceforge.net/  Also, check out [this example](http://kernelnewbies.org/Simple_UDP_Server) for UDP.

For Windows: Go to [this page](http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/) and downlaod both the HttpDisk and KHttpd samples. Both feature a windows device driver than makes use of a similar "ksocket" library.  (Look for ksocket.c and ksocket.h in each)

Comment: I think I didn't describe the question properly. I monitor and modify Ethernet packet myself, if I use OS socket library even kernel socket then the OS use its own gateway, own Ethernet network or maybe VPN network. Actually I already create strange layer over Ethernet network and it already work with UDP well and now I need to create tcp-connection too, the issue is that implementing and connection such as handshake and other stuff is time consuming.
My project has MIT license and I can use most open source project if any.

Comment: More details - what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Ok, got it. You got a packet filtering solution in place today, but you need to extend it to also make external connections.  Still not sure why you couldn't use ksockets. P2P and tunneling are two keen interests of mine for my own side projects. Would love to discuss this over email.

Comment: How can I discuss you over email? I have not your email. my email is madnik7@gmail.com

Comment: @Madnik7G Could you _at least_ tell the community which OS you are using?

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, use the `kernel_*()` versions of the usual socket API, i.e. `kernel_bind()`, `kernel_listen()`, `kernel_accept()`, `kernel_connect()`. They're in [`#include <linux/net.h>`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/net.h;hb=HEAD) and are used in ways very similar to "normal" sockets.

Solaris has very similar interfaces, there named `ksocket_*()`, see [`#include <sys/ksocket.h>`](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/ksocket.h) for references.

For the *BSD UN*X flavours, Apple's [Network Kernel Extensions Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/intro/intro.html) gives some details (also with references to the corresponding interfaces on Free/Net/OpenBSD).

Don't know about Windows.